# What's the purpose of adding a header to a AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this jQuery AJAX call we have a `header`, what is the uses of this? Why should we use it?

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/test",
   headers: { "X-Test-Header": "test-value" }
});
```

Comment: The usage of the header is entirely dependant on the recipient of the request.

Comment: It's just another way to send a piece of data to the server.

Answer (score 1):

It's a **Request Header.** HTTP header fields are components of the header section of request and response messages in the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP). They define the operating parameters of an HTTP transaction.

**Request Header:** The information, in the form of a text record, that a user's browser sends to a Web server containing the details of what the browser wants and will accept back from the server. The request header also contains the type, version and capabilities of the browser that is making the request so that server returns compatible data.
Upon receipt of the request header, the server will return an HTTP response header to the client that is attached to the file(s) being sent.